# Hyperlink breaks Image Overlay Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So the current code works when you mouse over or touch the thumbnail, an overlay occurs.

The problem is that you need to click exactly on the texts to go to the specific url, but the overlay isn’t clickable (can’t hyperlink you to another url).

I tried moving the `<a href>` by wrapping the overlay, posts, etc. but the entire code breaks.

I’ve also tried shifting `<a href>` inside the overlay div but it doesn’t work.

How do I get the overlay to be clickable and hyperlinked too, not only the texts?

I want the **text** AND the **overlay** to be clickable so that it takes you to another url.

Also the code in question:

HTML

```
<div class="js-masonry">
    <?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post();?>
    <div class="item-masonry overlay">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
        <div class="posts">
            <p><h2>text1</h2></p>
            <p><h2>Why is this text only clickable but the overlay doesn't?</h2></p>
            <p><h3>text2</3></p>
        </div>
        <img src="#"/>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; else: endif;?>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.posts {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.overlay:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.overlay:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codepen has invalid html. The anchor tag isn't closed.

Your issue is that your after element on `.overlay` is covering up the anchor, but as `.posts` is position absolute, it allows it to be above the overlay. This fix just increases the height of the text container and aligns the text to the bottom.

Add

```
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
```

to `.posts`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer to explain what this does and how it fixes the problem, so that it is a useful answer to other users also.